# Python3 virtual environments - eric7

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

Ubuntu 22.04. I have several projects in separate virtual environments, but I also installed eric7 in its own venv.

"Obviously", my projects need to live in a venv that supports their package requirements, but those may well be very different from the venv that eric7 requires. Currently, I'm editing in emacs and running my target scripts under bash (activated to the project venv) but I'd really like to run under Eric.

Which do I activate? When? How? (Activate Eric7, then run it, then activate the project venv? How to do that? I don't see any option in Eric7 to activate a different venv.)

Note that I've observed that when running eric7 under the project venv (via bash), some of the project packages aren't found. Activating the eric7 venv is just as unuseful.

Comment: [Cite](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) an eric7 documentation URL that you're following, please. What you describe makes sense to me. I don't know how eric7 expects you to manage things. Certainly with jetbrains PyCharm it's necessary to tell it about your various conda / venv / poetry project environments. That way the IDE has enough information to be able to helpfully auto-complete module / function names and so on.

Comment: Tried adding a virtual env through the Start->Debug Script->Virtual Environment; then through Settings->Preferences->Debugger->Python3->Virtual Environment to no good effect. Finally found a python icon in the IDE on the right that identifies itself at "Virtual Environments" where new venvs can be defined and then subsequently chosen in the debugging/running choices.

Comment: I am reading the [installation docs](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/eric-download.html) where they explain "It is recommended to install eric into a Python virtual environment." I think that means "into your project environment", so if you're working on two projects you'd have two copies of eric7 installed. At that point, it would be _easy_ for the IDE to located project dependencies, since everything is all together.

Comment: Interesting; I read that as recommending that eric be installed into its own virtual environment, whence it could be run without interference from other programs. Now that I discovered how to point eric to virtual environments, I'm running into other questions - my project relies on PySide6 venv and my project has its own venv, separate from PySide6. Maybe I need to study Python virtual environments more... TYVM for the note.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Fifth icon down allows new virtual environments to be identified, and subsequently chosen]

Screenshot of the region where a virtual environment can be defined for the runtime environment. Fifth icon down allows new virtual environments to be identified, and subsequently chosen.